# Remove music (waiting music) when a call is triggered

Tags: twilio, call

I want to remove the music when a call is triggered and one device is waiting for the other to pick up the call.
Could be?
Hangup hangup = new Hangup.Builder().build();
or
Dial dial = new Dial.Builder()

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
set waitUrl to ""
Conference conference = new Conference.Builder(conferenceRoom).statusCallback(conferenceCallbackUrl).waitUrl("").statusCallbackEvents(Arrays.asList(Event.START,

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!